# Google Classroom API Integration with the spring boot

Tags: google-classroom

I want to setup google 2-legged OAuth using service account. Below is my requirement.

- I have one G-Suite Admin account. Lets say googleclassroom.admin@xyz.com
- I have created few courses using admin account.
- Now I want to manage googleclassroom.admin@xyz.com classroom and its data  using service account. How can I configured and setup service account and project in google cloud?

Comment: This documentation should provide you with a good starting point: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-create-console

Comment: Thank you for the response, I already created service account.. I want to access user (googleclassroom.admin@xyz.com) classroom data using service account. Or If I create classroom using service account then it should display in user screen. 

Note: googleclassroom.admin@xyz.com is admin account..